# ViewModel com INSERT em dois Controllers

Tags: c#, .net, viewmodel

Possuo dois Controllers:

1 - Cadastra o CPF (CPF, Nome)

2 - Cadastro o Telefone do CPF (CPF, DDD, Telefone)

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace WebAutenticado.ViewModel
{
    public class NovoDevedorViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(14)]
        public string CPF_DEV { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string NOME_DEV { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string CONTRATO_FIN { get; set; }

        public byte COD_CLI { get; set; }

        public byte COD_CAR { get; set; }

        public int? COD_BOR { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string TIPO_FIN { get; set; }

        public double? VALOR_FIN { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(1)]
        public string MOEDA_FIN { get; set; }

        public int COD_TEL { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string DDD_TEL { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string TEL_TEL { get; set; }

        public byte COD_TIPO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

O Controle da Pessoa (CPF), funciona o cara insere na base, mas o clicar no CADASTRAR ele só passa no Create do primeiro controle (Pessoa).

Preciso fazer com que ao inserir a Pessoa (CPF) na base após ele vá para o Controle de Telefone e cadastre o Telefone com o CPF cadastrado no Controle de Pessoa.

**View da ViewModel:**

```
@model WebAutenticado.ViewModel.NovoDevedorViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Enviar Devedores";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Novo Cliente</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Cadastro de novo devedor</h4>
        <hr />
        <blockquote>Dados do Devedor</blockquote>

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF_DEV, "CPF/CNPJ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF_DEV, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF_DEV, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NOME_DEV, "Razao Social", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NOME_DEV, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NOME_DEV, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <blockquote>Telefones de Contato</blockquote>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COD_TEL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.COD_TEL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COD_TEL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DDD_TEL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDD_TEL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDD_TEL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TEL_TEL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TEL_TEL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TEL_TEL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COD_TIPO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.COD_TIPO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COD_TIPO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        <blockquote>Endereços de Contato</blockquote>
        <hr />
        <blockquote>Dados do Contrato</blockquote>
        <hr />
        <blockquote>Dados de Título</blockquote>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Próximo" class="btn btn-warning" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Retornar", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-xl btn-success" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Controller do Cadastro (CPF):**

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CPF_DEV,NOME_DEV,NASC_DEV,RG_DEV,EXP_DEV,ORG_DEV,MAE_DEV,PAI_DEV,CONJNOME_DEV,CONJCPF_DEV,PROFISSAO_DEV,RENDA_DEV,COD_SEXO,COD_ESTCIV,COD_TIPESS,NAC_DEV,EMAIL_DEV,RESID_DEV,OCUPA_DEV,TEMPORESID_DEV,TPDOC_DEV,NATURA_DEV,COD_UF,CPF_AUX,EMPRESA_DEV,DDD_DEV,DTNASC_DEV,VIRCOBWEBENVIO_DEV,ESCOLARIDADE_DEV,DTSALARIO_DEV,DTENVIODEBT_DEV,VIRCOBWEBSENHA_DEV")] CAD_DEV cAD_DEV)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CAD_DEV.Add(cAD_DEV);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(cAD_DEV);
    }
```

**Controler do Telefone:**

```
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CPF_DEV,COD_TEL,DDD_TEL,TEL_TEL,PERC_TEL,COD_TIPO,OBS_TEL,STATUS_TEL,COD_CLI,COD_REF,CLASSIFICACAO,COD_TIPO_DISCADOR,PRIORIDADE_TEL,EFICAZ_TEL,COD_HORARIOLIGACAO,COD_ORIGEM,RECUP_CONFIRM,RECUP_NEGATIV,DTNEGATIV_TEL,DTCONFIRM_TEL,OPERADORA,COD_OPERADORA,BLOQUEIO_TEL,OBSIMP_TEL,ORDEMPRIORIDADE_TEL,APTOSMS_TEL,POSSUIWHATSAPP_TEL,CELULARSN_TEL,DTINCLUSAO_TEL,SCORE_TEL")] CAD_DEVT cAD_DEVT)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CAD_DEVT.Add(cAD_DEVT);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(cAD_DEVT);
        }
```

**Model do Telefone:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace WebAutenticado.Models
{


    public partial class CAD_DEVT
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [StringLength(14)]
        public string CPF_DEV { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int COD_TEL { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string DDD_TEL { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string TEL_TEL { get; set; }

        public int PERC_TEL { get; set; }

        public byte COD_TIPO { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string OBS_TEL { get; set; }

        public int? STATUS_TEL { get; set; }

        public int? COD_CLI { get; set; }

        public int? COD_REF { get; set; }

        public int? CLASSIFICACAO { get; set; }

        [StringLength(6)]
        public string COD_TIPO_DISCADOR { get; set; }

        public int? PRIORIDADE_TEL { get; set; }

        public int? EFICAZ_TEL { get; set; }

        public int? COD_HORARIOLIGACAO { get; set; }

        public int? COD_ORIGEM { get; set; }

        public int? RECUP_CONFIRM { get; set; }

        public int? RECUP_NEGATIV { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DTNEGATIV_TEL { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DTCONFIRM_TEL { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60)]
        public string OPERADORA { get; set; }

        public int? COD_OPERADORA { get; set; }

        public byte? BLOQUEIO_TEL { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string OBSIMP_TEL { get; set; }

        public int? ORDEMPRIORIDADE_TEL { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string APTOSMS_TEL { get; set; }

        public byte? POSSUIWHATSAPP_TEL { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? CELULARSN_TEL { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DTINCLUSAO_TEL { get; set; }

        public byte? SCORE_TEL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Mappers:**

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAutenticado.Models;
using WebAutenticado.ViewModel;

namespace WebAutenticado.Mappers
{
    public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        // Não realizar este override na versão 4.x e superiores
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "DomainToViewModelMappings"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<CAD_DEV, NovoDevedorViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<CAD_DEVF, NovoDevedorViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<CAD_DEVE, NovoDevedorViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<CAD_DEVT, NovoDevedorViewModel>();

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebAutenticado.ViewModel;
using WebAutenticado.Models;

namespace WebAutenticado.Mappers
{
    public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        // Não realizar este override na versão 4.x e superiores
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappings"; }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<NovoDevedorViewModel, CAD_DEV>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<NovoDevedorViewModel, CAD_DEVF>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<NovoDevedorViewModel, CAD_DEVT>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<NovoDevedorViewModel, CAD_DEVE>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Pensei que ficaria assim:**

```
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CPF_DEV,NOME_DEV,NASC_DEV,RG_DEV,EXP_DEV,ORG_DEV,MAE_DEV,PAI_DEV,CONJNOME_DEV,CONJCPF_DEV,PROFISSAO_DEV,RENDA_DEV,COD_SEXO,COD_ESTCIV,COD_TIPESS,NAC_DEV,EMAIL_DEV,RESID_DEV,OCUPA_DEV,TEMPORESID_DEV,TPDOC_DEV,NATURA_DEV,COD_UF,CPF_AUX,EMPRESA_DEV,DDD_DEV,DTNASC_DEV,VIRCOBWEBENVIO_DEV,ESCOLARIDADE_DEV,DTSALARIO_DEV,DTENVIODEBT_DEV,VIRCOBWEBSENHA_DEV")] CAD_DEV cAD_DEV)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CAD_DEV.Add(cAD_DEV);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "CadastroDevedorTelefone", new { id = cAD_DEV.CPF_DEV });
            }

            return View(cAD_DEV);
        }
```

Comment: por favor adicione o código fonte do model telefone

Comment: Atualizado, precisa de algo mais?

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu diria que o que você quer fazer seria desnecessário. Você pode utilizar o mesmo controller para adicionar os dois registros sem problemas.

Exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CPF_DEV,NOME_DEV,NASC_DEV,RG_DEV,EXP_DEV,ORG_DEV,MAE_DEV,PAI_DEV,CONJNOME_DEV,CONJCPF_DEV,PROFISSAO_DEV,RENDA_DEV,COD_SEXO,COD_ESTCIV,COD_TIPESS,NAC_DEV,EMAIL_DEV,RESID_DEV,OCUPA_DEV,TEMPORESID_DEV,TPDOC_DEV,NATURA_DEV,COD_UF,CPF_AUX,EMPRESA_DEV,DDD_DEV,DTNASC_DEV,VIRCOBWEBENVIO_DEV,ESCOLARIDADE_DEV,DTSALARIO_DEV,DTENVIODEBT_DEV,VIRCOBWEBSENHA_DEV")] CAD_DEV cAD_DEV)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CAD_DEV.Add(cAD_DEV);
                db.OUTRODBSET.Add(OutroObjeto);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "CadastroDevedorTelefone", new { id = cAD_DEV.CPF_DEV });
            }

            return View(cAD_DEV);
        }
```

Caso seja necessário ir ao outro controller, você pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { model = ModelQueVoceQuerPassar });
```

lembrando que o "model" tem que ter o mesmo nome do seu parametro da action que você vai acessar.

Comment: Você está correto, dei muita volta.

Comment: @MarcosRebitte se puder avaliar a minha resposta, ficaria agradecido :D

Comment: Feito, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada foi a seguinte:

```html
public ActionResult Create(NovoDevedorViewModel devedorViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var cadDevViewModel = Mapper.Map<CAD_DEV>(devedorViewModel);
                var cadDevTViewModel = Mapper.Map<CAD_DEVT>(devedorViewModel);
                var cadDevEViewModel = Mapper.Map<CAD_DEVE>(devedorViewModel);
                var cadDevFViewModel = Mapper.Map<CAD_DEVF>(devedorViewModel);

                db.CAD_DEV.Add(cadDevViewModel);
                db.CAD_DEVT.Add(cadDevTViewModel);
                db.CAD_DEVE.Add(cadDevEViewModel);
                db.CAD_DEVF.Add(cadDevFViewModel);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(devedorViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: crédito aos Fabricio Oliveira (@gnomoskt).